# Setting text as a hyperlink javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm trying to set "Student 1, " as a link to the page it appears on.
How would I combine this `name = "Student 1, " + window.location.href;` so that Student is a link back to it's page?

I'm setting the student name in the javascript code:

```
function getFavourite()
{
    name = "Student 1, " + window.location.href;
    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + ' ' + name);
    saveFavourites();
    loadFavourites();
}
```

When a button is clicked the student name is added to a favorites box, I'm trying to turn the name into a hyperlink which links back to the students page.

Comment: You mean: how to construct this in HTML? Where does the student name come from?

Comment: I'm setting the student name in the javascript code

    function getFavourite()
   {

    name = "Student 1, " + window.location.href;

    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + ' ' + name) ;
    saveFavourites();
    loadFavourites();
   }
   
When a button is clicked the student name is added to a favourites box, I'm trying to turn the name into a hyperlink which links back to the students page.

Answer (score 0):

I have created [a little sample](http://jsfiddle.net/CLhYV/) for you that should do the trick. You can alter it the way you want to.

HTML:

```
<input id="input" />
<button onclick="javascript:getFavourite()">test</button>
<div id="output" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getFavourite()
{
    name = 'Student 1 ' + $('#input').val();
    $('#output').html('<a href=' + window.location.href + '?student=' + $('#input').val() + '>' + name + '</a>');
}
```

Comment: @user3599124: Any luck testing this? Was this helpful?

Comment: Thanks for your responce, I've tried using it I couldn't get it to work. I'm now trying to use document.createElement('a'); but still its not totally working.

Comment: @user3599124: Where did you have trouble using my example? Create a jsfiddle from what you have got including that and I will take a look for you.

Comment: For some reason it displayed all the student names in the box. http://jsfiddle.net/fMx5Y/ This is what I'm trying just now on my computer it displays the url of the page but not as a link or with the students name. It doesn't seem to be appearing on jsfiddle though

Comment: @user3599124: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fMx5Y/1/. Also, when using jsfiddle. Don't forget to set the settings right at the left ('use jQuery' and 'load javascript in head')

Comment: It still only displays the url and not as a link. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: You cannot add links in a input field. Try to do it elsewhere, like in a div. My code should give you an idea. Also, your input field is the same as your output field, which is weird.